# Simple Data Entry form in VB.net Via Relational Table

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0

I am creating data entry form in  vb.net. I have three tables 1.orders,2. orderdetails 3. product

Orderid- Primary key for Order table and foreign key for Orderdetail table.

In Dataentry form , I need when I load form , value of orderid from ordertable should automatically load in orderid colum of ordertable.

overall I want to create data entry form via related tables, please suggest how I can do .

Answer (score 0):

You can write Store procedure for that. in that you need to write sql query with inner join with two tables.

i.e.

```
Select <Fields>
from Orders A, OrderDetails B
where A.orderID= b.OrderID
```

And you will get all the value of orderid from orders and Orderdetails tables.
Write code for this in form load then you will meet your requirement.